# Simply including SDL header causes linker error

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, xcode4, sdl

I was going to migrate my game from glut to sdl.

It's working perfectly in glut but I wanted to use some sdl features.

So I go into my project properties, under the targets header I click the program that will be compiled, build phases, link binary with libraries, add SDL.framework

The exact same as I have done for OpenGL.framework and GLUT.framework

However when I add: `#include <SDL/SDL.h>` it comes up with a linker error when I try to build:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
      __start in crt1.o
     (maybe you meant: _SDL_main)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Googling simply leads to a fair few results, but no real explanations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SDL uses a macro to rename your `main(..)` and should supply its own, usually implemented in `SDLmain.m`. It should be supplied together with the SDL.framework.

When you download the framework from here http://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php Read the `ReadMeDevLite.txt` in the `devel-lite` folder.

Another description 
http://www.meandmark.com/sdlopenglpart2.html

Comment: I'm rather new to Mac based development, not even sure what a .m file is, could you explain how I would go about sorting such things out?

Comment: @Blam, A .m file is an Objective-C file. The Mac version of SDL is written in Objective-C. Add the files SDLMain.h and SDLMain.m to your project. They contain glue code you need to compile SDL apps on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that when I get the error :

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_main", referenced from:
      implicit entry/start for main executable
       (maybe you meant: _SDL_main)

I have forgotten to go to Project -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources and add SDLMain.m to the list. This solved the problem for me right away.