# SDL with g++ on OSX Lion

Tags: c++, g++, osx-lion, sdl

Dose anyone know how to set up SDL (simple direct media layer) on OSX Lion so I can compile my code with g++ ?
I have read the "readme" that comes with the package and I have placed the frameworks folder in the relevant directory, however, this does not seem to be enough.
Can anyone help me ?
(I do not want to use Xcode)

Comment: Which errors are you getting? You probably need to tell g++ to link with the SDL binaries

Comment: This is the exact error i get:
    library not found for -lSDLmain
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    Joes-MacBook-Pro:SDL Joe$ g++ main.cpp -framework SDL
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_main", referenced from:
          start in crt1.10.6.o
         (maybe you meant: SDL_main())
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: It seems like before calling g++ with the `-framework` option, you need to call it with the `-ln` option. Take a look at [this](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/languages/C++/InstallingC++graphicslibs.html), in the MacOs subsection.

Comment: Just created a symbolic link to the SDL framework directory and i'm still getting the same error

Comment: [This guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071971/simply-including-sdl-header-causes-linker-error) got the same error and solved it.

Comment: When I get that main error it is usually from not have the main.m and main.h files that are included with SDL in my project. Try adding those. Here is a [tutorial](http://samwalkercs.blogspot.com/2011/12/setting-up-sdl-to-work-with-xcode-42-on.html) that works for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're not using XCode, and are compiling SDL projects using `gcc`, you can run:

```
gcc -o test SDLTest.c `sdl-config --cflags --libs` 
g++ -o test SDLText.c `sdl-config --cflags --libs`
```

This works happily for me on my mac - `sdl-config --version` returns `1.2.14`, and I can run `test` :)