# Connect sdl to visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, sdl

I try to connect sdl to visual c++ like [this](http://www.libsdl.org/tmp/SDL/VisualC.html), but have the problem.
I just include SDL.h and have errors:

```
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: ёё√ыър эр эхЁрчЁх°хээ√щ тэх°эшщ ёшьтюы _main т ЇєэъЎшш ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\Zhenya\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: эхЁрчЁх°хээ√ї тэх°эшї ¤ыхьхэЄют: 1
```

Sorry for the encoding, I think you will understand error code.
What's the problem?

Comment: Maybe this is what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071971/simply-including-sdl-header-causes-linker-error

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a function named [`main`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh.aspx). That's where your program will start execution.

Comment: but I have a function named main

Comment: If you had a function named `main`, the linker wouldn't be telling you that it can't find a function named `main`. Perhaps you forgot to add a source file defining `main` to the project?

Comment: My code:`#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
 #include "SDL.h"

  extern "C" {

#include "avcodec.h"
#include "avformat.h"
#include "swscale.h" 
 } 
using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
 av_register_all();
    return 0;
}`

Comment: That is not the [correct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ta3zst.aspx) [form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh.aspx) of `main`.

Comment: But this is a standard definition of main function in clr console application

Comment: Not according to MSDN documentation. Since you don't seem to know how to follow a link, I'll spell out the URL for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ta3zst.aspx

Comment: Do you mean that I should change  function arguments? If so, it did not help

Comment: Ok, sorry, maybe I don't understand, because I work with this for the first time. So can you explain more understandable, please.