# How to run ffplay as a window-less process?

Tags: ffmpeg, sdl

I am running ffplay as a background process which supplies image data to my main UI process. I have set "`SDL_VIDEODRIVER = dummy`" to suppress the ffplay video being shown in a SDL window.

The issue is that the ffplay process still appears as an application window (dock, CMD+TAB entries etc.) even if the video output window is not displayed. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dock entry was being added by SDLMain.m which [needs to be compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019892/compiling-sdl-on-a-mac) into `ffplay` for it to play on a Mac. After commenting the following lines in SDLMain.m, ffplay is running as a window-less process.

```
//#ifdef SDL_USE_CPS
//    {
//        CPSProcessSerNum PSN;
//        /* Tell the dock about us */
//        if (!CPSGetCurrentProcess(&PSN))
//            if (!CPSEnableForegroundOperation(&PSN,0x03,0x3C,0x2C,0x1103))
//                if (!CPSSetFrontProcess(&PSN))
//                    [NSApplication sharedApplication];
//    }
//#endif /* SDL_USE_CPS */

/* Set up the menubar */
//[NSApp setMainMenu:[[NSMenu alloc] init]];
//setApplicationMenu();
//setupWindowMenu();
```

**Edit** This only affects Mac since we don't need the `SDLMain.m` wrapper around `int main()` on other platforms

Answer (score 30):

The option `-nodisp` worked fine for me (together with `-autoexit`).

Tested in a Ubuntu 18.04, ffmpeg 3.4.6:

```
ffplay -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=1000:duration=5" -autoexit -nodisp
```

Source: [[FFmpeg-user] ffplay for audio only](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2011-March/000044.html)

Comment: Confirmed that `-nodisp` works on Windows 11 also.